# Initial conditions of nbody problem

Tags: simulation, conservation

*Note: I have edited the original question to try to be clearer.*

I'm trying to simulate a gravitational nbody problem with a Barnes-Hut algorithm, in which the bodies start in a homogeneous sphere with random velocities. Because of this, the initial angular momentum is almost zero. I have tested the code with things like the solar system and compared its results to a brute force algorithm and it seems to work fine.

Despite using very low time steps (I'm using a velocity verlet integrator, if that matters) the angular momentum increases a lot, not being conserved at all. This image shows a typical increase of the momentum (later I will show more detailled data)

[image: L increase]

You can see that the energy is being conserved perfectly but the angular momentum keeps increasing with the bodies being accelerated. All the angular momentums are computed from the actual center of mass of the cluster.

When a body has a close encounter and gets expelled from the cluster, both the angular momentum and the energy increase a lot:

[image: A body gets expelled]

I have tried different timesteps (from $\delta t= 10^{-8}t_0$ to $\delta t=10^{-3}t_0$) <del>and gravitational softening parameters $\epsilon$ (from $F_{ij} \propto r_{ij}(\epsilon + r_{ij}^3)^{-1}$) from $1$ light year to $10^{-5}$ light years (the initial separation between bodies is $6$ ly),</del> and they all have the same general results (there are 8 series in each line but the deviation is minimal):

[image: Evolution of the system]

The sudden rise of the lines is caused by a body being expelled by a close encounter. My principal concern is the initial increase of the angular momentum, because it doesn't come with a variation in the total energy. Because real galaxies have angular momentum, I thought that maybe I should start the simulation with a non zero angular momentum.

My questions are:

- What are the standard initial conditions in this kind of problems? They involve a small initial angular momentum or they use a "spinning" cluster to begin the simulation?
- Which variation in angular momentum and energy can be considered reasonable in nbody simulations?

Edit: I wasn't aplying gravitational softening, but it does not change the results.

Edit: This is the relevant code of the angular momentum, I can see a flaw but who knows...

```
double acc = 0;
for(int i=0;i<nstars;i++){
    double r[3] = { x[i]-cmx , y[i]-cmy , z[i]-cmz };
    double v[3] = { vx[i] , vy[i] , vz[i] };
    double li[3] = { r[1]*v[2]-r[2]*v[1], -(r[0]*v[2] - r[2]*v[0]),  r[0]*v[1] - r[1]*v[0] };
    // Li = Rᵢ×Vᵢ
    acc += m[i]*norm(li);
    // acc += m⋅R×V
    }
return acc;
```

cmx, cmy, cmz are the coordinates of the mass (just checked, it doesn't move a bit and it's where it should be). Using a fixed reference frame makes no difference.

Edit: Just tried gravitational softening (it was badly implemented). It helps a lot to avoid bodies fly away, but makes no difference in the constant increase of the angular momentum.

[image: gravitational softening]

Comment: Regarding the reasonable variation in angular momentum, I think that is a question more suitable for Physics.StackExchange.

Comment: It's the angular momentum the only increasing quantity? What about the kinetic energy of the overall system?

Comment: I don't understand why the initial angular momentum should be zero. If you are starting with randomly distributed particles with randomly distributed initial velocities, then the *expectation value* of the overall angular momentum will be zero, but the angular momentum of a concrete realization will *not* have a zero angular momentum.

Comment: Have you tested your code on simple cases?  If you haven't, start with a 2-body problem and check that it converges to the exact solution.  You want to rule out outright bugs before you start looking for more subtle things.

Comment: A good reference on galactic modeling is the text by Binney & Tremaine.

Comment: I have edited the question to try to adress your questions. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @nicoguaro Yes, the kinetic energy also increases as the cluster collapses.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Yes, the code is tested with a 4-body solar system (Sun, Mercury, Venus and Earth). Thank you for the reference!

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I should have sayed that is very small compared to the final angular momentum after a small number of steps. It rises very quickly, and the initial value is small (the bodies have a very small initial velocity, and are almost fixed). Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: If you set n=2 in your simulation, what happens to the angular momentum?  It seems clear that there is a bug somewhere, so I suggest trying simpler problems until you find it.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Nice point! After aplying some softening to avoid a "colision" I obtain the same results, only less exagerated. Being more detailled:


1 body: Constant energy, null angular momentum
2 body: Constant energy, momentum increases but still negligible
3 body: Constant energy (small fluctuations with big timesteps), Momentum increases from 1e-17 to almost 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39224/discussion-between-redpointyjackson-and-david-ketcheson).

Comment: The problem seems to be in the 'collision'. As bodies get very close with an increased speed, the grid size and temporal step size are too big. A solution to this might be using an adaptive algorithm.

Comment: @AdrianRoman That's indeed a problem, but I have solved it with a softening parameter in Newton's Law. Also, that doesn't explain the initial increase in angular momentum, only the peaks.

Comment: I would make sure that the angular momentum is correctly calculated. Perhaps use a fixed reference frame to calculate it instead of the center of mass. If possible, use a higher order symplectic integrator, see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @AdrianRoman Just tried the fixed reference frame, same result. Also checked the angular momentum function, and seems fine (and works for a solar system fine). I can't try an higher order integrator right now, but I checked with an Euler to see if I had implemented the velocity Verlet wrongly but also there is no difference.

Comment: Euler is quite bad anyway... I was just looking over your code and I don't quite get it. You calculate a scalar quantity for angular momentum, but angular momentum is a (pseudo)vector. Lose the 'norm' call and calculate the (psedo)vector. If you are interested in its length only, call it at the end for the whole sum. The length of a vector is usually not the sum of lengths of the summed vectors.

Comment: @AdrianRoman You couldn't be more right. What a mistake! If you want, make your comment an answer and I will vote you. Now, the momentum doesn't rise so much, and keeps a reasonably low value. Thank you!